# Bench testing OBDII dongle

Tags: automotive, obd

I'm currently trying to connect my wifi obd2 dongle directly to a VW ecu that is powered by a bench power supply.

I followed the guide here:

http://www.nefariousmotorsports.com/wiki/index.php/ECU_Bench_Flashing

And it looks like the dongle is getting power as the led is lit up and I can see the obd wifi ssid, but when I try to connect I am given the error "Unable to connect"

What am I missing?

(the dongle works when I use it in the car)

Answer (score 2):

**"Unable to Connect..."** is a message coming from the ELM inside your OBD2 wifi device. Make sure you [look through the documentation thoroughly](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf)

You likely need to **signal to the ECU** that the key is inserted, ignition "on". Otherwise the ECU goes to low power mode shutting down the bus so as to avoid killing your battery.

**Look at the wiring diagram from the ACC line--** accessories-- and see where it's coming from-- and going to-- somewhere in there is a wire to the ECU that says "hey, there's a key plugged in here"

Comment: The unable to connect message is displayed on my iPhone when trying to join the wifi network, it's more like it's struggling to join the hotspot.

However I was unaware of the low power mode of the ECU, so thanks for the heads up, that explains why its only drawing 0.01A

Comment: oh right, I should have read closer!!